# Background image using a remote url

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AlgoStash</title>
<style>
html { 
  background: url("<?php echo base_url('assets/sea.jpg');?>" no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="<?php echo base_url('assets/avinu.mp3');?>" autoplay></audio>
</body>
<!-- אבא שלנו, המלך שלנו -->
</html>
```

that produces this html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AlgoStash</title>
<style>
html { 
  background: url("http://algopesa.com/assets/sea.jpg" no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="http://algopesa.com/assets/avinu.mp3" autoplay></audio>
</body>
<!-- אבא שלנו, המלך שלנו -->
</html>
```

However, the page does not display the image.

Why does this code

```
html { 
  background: url("http://algopesa.com/assets/sea.jpg" no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

not produce the background image although the image is present?. How can i make the image display?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the `url(... )`, otherwise it will not work:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AlgoStash</title>
<style>
html { 
  background: url("<?php echo base_url('assets/sea.jpg');?>") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="<?php echo base_url('assets/avinu.mp3');?>" autoplay></audio>
</body>
<!-- אבא שלנו, המלך שלנו -->
</html>
```